# Simple void method works but Coroutine throws a null reference exception

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, coroutine

I am Unity beginner and trying to activate a GameObject which I have referenced from the inspector and deactivate it after 3 seconds(with the help of Coroutine) and in the scene. I am not destroying the GameObject on which the Coroutine is attached to. Have spent so much time but still not able to figure out what's happening. When I replace the Coroutine with the simple void method it does not throws any exception but I have to use the Coroutine for the behavior I want.

[1][image: This is the code]

[[image: This is the exception]]

[image]

Comment: When you paste code, paste text, not a picture.

Comment: I Think Dude, mostly null reference exception will come only when our game object is not assigned references. first, check this thing. in your inspector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you for answering but sadly no that does not help.

Comment: Well it shoukd you need to debug to work out what is null. It wont be telling lies :(

Comment: If it works with void, you can define your method 'private async void ShowError()' and instead using 'waitForSeconds' use await 'Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))'. (Search for async/await for more information) However, I cannot tell why coroutine raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Dude,

mostly null reference exception will come only when our game object is not assigned references.

first, check this thing. in your inspector.

Like this->

[image: Look at that]

Comment: First of all Thank you for answering. Yes I have double checked it, everything is referenced properly.

Comment: As you can see I have edited my question and added the image of the component where the coroutine resides. I am neither deactivating it nor destroying it but still at the point where the coroutine has to run, it throws the null reference exception.